# PostgreSQL: SET TIME ZONE formatting

Tags: postgresql, timezone

Those give a correct result:

`SET TIME ZONE '-04';` or `SET TIME ZONE INTERVAL '-04:00';`

```
SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE'), now();
 current_setting |              now              
-----------------+-------------------------------
 -04:00:00       | 2014-10-29 06:45:35.694796-04
```

While those are inverted:

`SET TIME ZONE '-04:00';`

```
SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE'), now();
 current_setting |              now              
-----------------+-------------------------------
 -04:00          | 2014-10-29 14:52:25.322796+04
```

`SET TIME ZONE '-04:00:00';`

```
SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE'), now();
 current_setting |              now              
-----------------+-------------------------------
 -04:00:00       | 2014-10-29 14:52:33.591539+04
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd consider this a bug. It's because POSIX time zones are reversed from "normal" time zones. Please raise this via the bug report form.

Comment: @CraigRinger According to the below answer, do you still think it's a bug? Maybe at least this documented behavior deserves some improvement, like raising a warning when no POSIX-style timezone is recognized or requiring a explicit formatting when we want to use the POSIX-style?

Comment: I think it's a documented bug ;-)  . I knew POSIX timezone handling was ugly, but hadn't realised it was that ugly. We really need a `strict` mode for this. So it's not new, and there's no need to report it, but ... yuck.

Comment: @CraigRinger What about `current_setting('TIMEZONE')`? It's not reporting exactly the internal value because while displaying `-04:00:00` that could mean an internal `-04` or `+04`. It's the same with `SHOW TIMEZONE;`. Nothing in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) about that. Is that a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SET TIME ZONE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) has 3 forms (actually 4, with the two special value: `LOCAL` & `DEFAULT`); it can accept:

- a timezone abbreviation in a text,
- a timezone offset in a number (offset is actually in hours),
- a timezone offset in an interval

Also, need to mention, when you supply an invalid timezone abbreviation, the `SET` statement will [silently accept bogus input](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES):

> One should be wary that the POSIX-style time zone feature can lead to silently accepting bogus input, since there is no check on the reasonableness of the zone abbreviations.

Check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/2628), there you can see:

- `SET TIME ZONE '-04'` will set a timezone offset as a number (in hours)
- `SET TIME ZONE '-04:00'` will try to set a timezone with its abbreviation, but will silently fail
- `SET TIME ZONE '-04:00:00'` will also try to set a timezone with its abbreviation and will silently fail, but you'll get the intention that this statement was successful, because getting the current setting will give you your bogus timezone abbreviation, which can be interpreted as a valid one too (but that's not the case).

Always use a direct number, or an `INTERVAL` literal with `SET TIME ZONE`, or preferably: use valid timezone abbreviations, like `America/New_York`.